# django// 1054, Unknown column 'rank.post_id_id' in 'field list'"

Tags: python, django, inspectdb

django=2.2.3
mariadb

This error occurs after importing model from an existing database with 'inspectdb' and changed field properties.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Rank(models.Model):
    rank_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rank_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    # post_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Originally, it was # post_id, but I removed "managed = False", changed it to ForeignKey and then "migrate".
As far as I know that if the "post_id" in the "Post" model is "primary_key True", it replaces the "id" value with "post_id". But "Django" keeps calling up the "post_id_id".
There is no command to refer to post_id_id elsewhere.
If you have a solution or something that I'm missing, please give me some advice.

-------Add more after commented by Daniel Roseman --------

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    post_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    uid = models.AutoField(prymary_key=True)
    gallery_name = models.CharField(...)


class Rank(models.Model):
    rank_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rank_type = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    # post_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    post_id = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    # uid = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    uid = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your ForeignKey `post_id`. Call it `post`. The underlying database field is `post_id`; Django adds the `_id` suffix automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If possible, would you please take another look at my updated question? As you said, the post went well. But what should I do with field names if uid? raised "1054, Unknown column 'rank.uid_id' in 'field list'"

Comment: I don't really understand the update. Why have you used the name `uid` for the FK to Gallery? Why not `gallery`?